# Seleccionar todos los checkbox dentro de una etiqueta-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy tratando de seleccionar todos los Checkbox dentro de una etiqueta,
tengo un "pre" dentro de el están unos conceptos con su respectivo Checkbox la idea es que al desplegar el "pre" se seleccione el concepto Padre y que cuando se despliegue me muestre los conceptos hijo seleccionados.
Encontré un método que me selecciona los demás CHB's pero no lo hace cuando despliega la información tengo que picarle al CHB padre para que se seleccionen los demás y lo que yo quiero es que me lo haga en automático , cuando despliegue la información se seleccionen los CHB's hijos y cuando se oculte la información se desseleccionenen.
Me podrían ayudar en esto de utilizar javascript.
Saludos.

```js
 function MostrarOcultar(ref) {
            // Nodo del documento que se [muestra /oculta]
            // Tiene que tener un ID unico
            var nodoContraible = document.getElementById(ref);

            // Nodo que contiene el [enlace] que maneja el que se [muestra /oculta]
            // DEBE tener el mismo ID que el nodo [nodoContraible] pero precedido por una x
            var xNodoDelEnlace = document.getElementById("x" + ref);

            if (nodoContraible.style.display == 'none') {
                var nuevoValor = document.getElementById("x" + ref);
                xNodoDelEnlace.innerHTML = nuevoValor.textContent.replace("+", "-");
                nodoContraible.style.display = "block";

                //Cuando se haga click en un concepto padre los hijos se seleccionaran automaticamente
                var IdCB = "cb" + ref;
                document.getElementById(IdCB).checked = true;
                
                
            }
            else {
                var nuevoValor = document.getElementById("x"+ref);
                xNodoDelEnlace.innerHTML = nuevoValor.textContent.replace("-","+");
                nodoContraible.style.display = 'none';

                //Cuando se haga click en un concepto padre los hijos se seleccionaran automaticamente
                var IdCB = "cb" + ref;
                document.getElementById(IdCB).checked = false;
            }
        }
```

```css
 <style>
        .expandirContraerCSS {
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #AA0000;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: smaller;
            border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
            background-color: #2F5978;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        .pre_titulo {
            color: #ffffff;
            /*background-color: #EF6699;*/
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 0.5cm;
            margin-bottom: 0cm;
        }
            .pre_titulo:hover {
                color: #cccccc;
            }
            .pre_titulo:visited {
                color: #cccccc;
            }
pre
{
      background-color:#FBEDBB;
      padding-right: 7pt; 
      padding-left: 7pt;
      padding-bottom: 7pt; 
      padding-top: 7pt; 
      font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono;
      font-size:9pt;
      white-space: pre;
      overflow:auto;
}
    </style>
```

```html
<p id="pConcepto1" class="expandirContraerCSS">
<a class="pre_titulo" id="xConcepto1" onclick="MostrarOcultar('Concepto1');" href="#_self">
+  25 MULTAS DE TRÁNSITO 247,117.66
</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="listaConceptoDetalle" value=" 25|MULTAS DE TRÁNSITO|247,117.66" id="cbConcepto1"> 
</p>

<pre id="Concepto1" style="display: none;">
<input type="checkbox" name="listaConceptoDetalle" value="4111|MULTAS DE PARQUIMETROS|$2,201.07" id="4111"> 4111 MULTAS DE PARQUIMETROS $2,201.07
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="listaConceptoDetalle" value="4110|MULTAS DE TRANSITO|$244,916.59" id="4110"> 4110 MULTAS DE TRANSITO $244,916.59<br></pre>
```

Este es el método que encontré

```
function MarcaCasillasConceptoDetalle(cb_Padre,ref)
    {
        var direccion = "#" + ref + " > input[type=checkbox]";
        var seleccionar_todo = "#" + cb_Padre;
        $(function () {
            $(seleccionar_todo).change(function () {
                $(direccion).prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, no te sirve darles un Name a los checkbox y seleccionarlos todos por el name?

Comment: como seria eso @harifo? , no entraría en conflicto si tengo otros conceptos padre que desplegar?

Comment: puedes usar Jqery?